# Inserted Figure is Invisible

Tags: graphics

When I insert any figure into my Latex document all I get as the output is a total black background instead of the image (when I use switch [demo] on). However when I disable the demo, I get an error message

> LaTex could not determine the graphics size

What should I do in this case?

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
```

Comment: delete option `[demo]` when loading `graphicx` package.

Comment: Not needed here, but please note that all questions should include a complete, but minimal, document which demonstrates the problem. This would contain both too little and too much to be useful, if it were not for the fact that the problem is an extremely common one.